# Allowing CreateProcessWithLogonW calls from ASP.NET process running under IIS AppPool Identity

Tags: iis, permissions, asp.net

I [asked this over at StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56473102/82121) already and received no answer, so I wondered if maybe the ServerFault crowd might know a bit more.

What I'm basically asking is:

Is there a way to configure a concrete `IIS AppPool\MyApp` identity to allow for [`CreateProcessWithLogonW`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithlogonw) calls?

Since it is possible to configure arbitrary file-system permissions, surely there is a way to also allow spawning new processes with credentials, no?

If there really isn't any, then what is the recommended recourse? Would changing the AppPool Identity to `LocalService` or `NetworkService` be safe, security-wise?

Comment: I don't think the cause of the access denied error is quite as simple as that, `CreateProcessWithLogonW` isn't supposed to require any permissions to use.

Comment: Now, I'm behind the times, but how I'd have done this sort of thing in the old days would be to install a system service that would run as your interactive user and take requests from your ASP.NET application (probably via a named pipe) to launch the troublesome executable on your behalf.  Nowadays, couldn't you achieve the same thing more easily with something like WCF?

Comment: .... as I understand it, an ASP.NET application can consume a WCF service, and the WCF service can presumably be configured to run with a separate identity, i.e., the interactive user account.  That way, you wouldn't need to hard-code the credentials into your code.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, I'm aware of the separate service option. I simply didn't mention it, because it means quite some work for a supposedly simple task and I was primarily interested in first trying the "elegant way". Not to mention that additional service complicates deployment and management, because now there are two services to worry about.

Comment: I'd have thought a separate service *was* the elegant solution, but never mind. :-)  In that case you might want to further investigate the cause of the access denied error.  Does switching to `LocalService` actually solve your problem?  If so, it isn't ideal from a security perspective, but it isn't dreadful.  And have you experimented with `CreateProcessWithTokenW` as a possible alternative?